# Find Big O Running Time

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I am having difficulty figuring out the big o notation running time of this piece of code. I would think it's O(n) because i=0 and the first while loop keeps going until i = n but then the second while loop comes in and the whole thing is throwing me off.

```
i=0
sum = 0;
    while i<n:
       sum++
       if i==3 or i==7 or i==5:
          j=0
          while j<n:
             sum++
             j++
       i++
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It indeed is `O(n)`. If you had no if statements you would have `O(n^2)`. But inner loop is running at most 3 times so it is equivalent to `O(3n)` and `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop only executes, at most, 3 times. For large values of `n`, the total time spent in that loop will be inconsequential to the overall running time.

Comment: Okay so then that would mean that it's O(n) because that should be how many times the outer loop runs. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

It's still O(n). The second while loop take 3n time in the worse case .( n>=8)

Comment: What do you mean by `n >= 8`? Isn't that irrelevant in o-notation?

Comment: if n=<7 , the second while loop take 2n time or less ( it's not the worse case).